# jquery events doesn't trigger in Vuejs

Tags: jquery, vue.js, jquery-ui

I want to trigger an event with jquery in a Vue, but it doesn't show anything.

```
var panel = BasePanel.extend({
      data() {
        return {
          editLine: null,
          save: false, //show save button
          updatedLines: [],
          createdLines: [],
        };
      },
      mounted() {
        $('.diplomatic-line').on('dragstart', function(ev) {
          console.log("dragstart");
        });
      },
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How many panels do you have on a page? Do you realize every single one will bind a listener on each panel present in DOM at the moment it gets `mounted()`?